# ¿ Como obtener dato de un radio php a mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Hola estoy tratando de obtener el valor de un radio de html a php y de ahi a la bd se los muestro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de html esta asi:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">

            <h4>Tipo de vialidad</h4>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="vialidad" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
                        Primaria
                        </label>
                    </div>
                <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="vialidad" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
                        Secundaria
                        </label>
                </div>

            </div>

          </div>
```

De ahi lo que hago es que ese name lo mando a llamar en el codigo php de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este al final no funciona solo me borra los datos y no se inserta en la bd.

Comment: En el `PHP` hacés referencia a un campo `lumina`, de dónde sale? Por favor publicá el código completo y no como una imagen.

Comment: lumina es un campo input, ese me funciona a la perfección, pero cuando meto el de tipo de vialidad que son los radio ya no se inserta correctamente en la bd, lo puse en imagen porque no me deja poner todo, el stackoverflow me dice que es mucho código

Comment: Si antes de `$datos = array(...)` hacés un `var_dump($_POST['vialidad'])`, te muestra algo? Tal vez el error está dentro de `ModeloCenso::mdlIngresarCenso()`.

Comment: Ya vi el error amigo,si el error estaba en value que me enviaba el html, me di cuenta con el  `var_dump`